# Login automatically as root

Tags: shell-script, embedded

I am working with a board and when it finishes the boot, appears the login. What I want to do is login as root but automatically. I mean I want to do that when boot is finish, I can see the prompt, without login.

Comment: What is this board you're working with? What distro is it using? Also what version of the Linux kernel is it using?

Comment: An approach not unlike these: http://en.gnublin.org/index.php/Automatic_login_to_Gnublin will likely be how you go about it!

Comment: ArmStonea9, linux linaro

Comment: Oh duh, sorry, I'll fix that.

Comment: No problem, I am working with an board in which I just have a basic sysroot, even I can not make sudo...Then I can not get mingetty program

Comment: Does it have a `/etc/inittab` file? If so what getty is it using there?

Comment: yeah it has. inside there is this lines with getty:        1:1:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty1

Comment: 2:1:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty1

Comment: and mxc1::respawn:/sbin/getty -L ttymxc1 115200 vt100 #GENERIC SERIAL

Comment: So I'd edit the getty line per the directions in the URL I updated in comments to see if you can login w/o being prompted for a password.

Comment: sorry but I do not know what you mean?

Comment: Has anybody mentioned yet the volume of reasons why this is an incredibly bad idea?

Comment: Hi hymie, please let me know

Answer (score 5):

Within your `/etc/inittab` add the following line to login:

```
1:2345:respawn:/bin/login -f <username> tty1 </dev/tty1 >/dev/tty1 2>&1
```

Where `<username>` would be "root", if that's the login you're attempting to autologin with.

**NOTE:** Be sure to comment out any `getty` line that may already be present in the `/etc/inittab`. This line is replacing the program that manages the console with `login`.

#### References

- [etc/inittab auto login frustration~!](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=60915)
- [Automatic login to virtual console](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/automatic_login_to_virtual_console)

Comment: Do I just need to add thos line? or also I need to comment anyone?

Comment: @user3766585 - yes comment out the `getty` line and add this one right after it.

Answer (score 2):

There is also another answer to this problem. Try:

```
ttyPS0::respawn:/bin/login -f <username>
```

it should log you in automatically, at least when using busybox's login.

Comment: Omg, it is an inittab fragment? I didn't see that since a decade! But... I still want it back. systemd, broargh.